# Linker can't find Ogre libraries

Tags: linux, linker-errors, libraries, ogre

When attempting to compile under linux in CodeBlocks I get

```
cannot find -lOgreMain_d
```

and

```
cannot find -lOIS_d.
```

Under the linker settings I have

```
/usr/lib/libOgreTerrain.so
/usr/lib/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so
/usr/lib/libOgrePaging.so
/usr/lib/libOgreMain.so
/usr/lib/libOgreProperty.so
/usr/lib/libOIS-1.3.0.so
/usr/lib/libOIS.so
/usr/lib/libOIS.a
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect to find a library which isn't even there? Use:

```
gcc <options> -lOIS -lOgreMain
```

etc. Always specify libraries only which have a corresponding filename in /usr/lib or other standard library locations.

Comment: It looks like he/she wants to use the debug versions /*_d", so instead of changing the linker commands, he/she needs to tell the IDE where to find the debug SOs, so extend the list posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to install  `"libois-dev libboost-thread-dev".`

So you just have to type  `"sudo apt-get install  libois-dev   libboost"`   and  of course once you have done this you will have them installed in your  `/usr/include/ois`   directory.

Comment: why boost? it is not required to run/create an OGre3D application!